# controlling size of UIView using its frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, frame

I am working on an ipad ios7 application and I am trying to add a custom view that I derive from UIView and set up a nib file for to an existing view. I can add the view just fine, but when I try to set the frame for the view the view does not show properly within the frame.

Is there a way to have a view automatically fit within its frame that I set? Or is the frame only used to control location on the screen in which case how do I have my view size to fit a certain area?

Thanks

Comment: Use autolayout on the XIB to position and size your subviews properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the nib, add all the necessary auto-layout constraints to position and size the view as you want.

Comment: will that make it size to fit any frame I give it then?

Comment: Yes, you can force the size of the view by using the height and width constraints, or you can size and position them relative to its superview, by using leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints.

Comment: thanks I will have to give that a shot. I had set up constraints between subviews on the view but I didn't set up constraints for the view itself. I'll be sure to mark this as the answer once I get my view set up.